# Extracting a specific part of a URL using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm fairly new to any kind of language but I need to modify a code at my work because the guy doing it previously left and no replacement.

I basically would like to put in a variable a specific part of a url.

The URLs look like this:

> http://www.test.com/abc/hhhhhh/a458/example

I need to extract the `a458` part and put it in a variable. This part is always at the same place but can be of variable length.

The URLs always have the same structure. I tried `/hhhhhh\/{1}[a-z0-9]+\/{1}/g` but it doesn't fully work. It keeps the `hhh` and the `/`.

Comment: Will links always be `http://test.com/abc/hhhhhh/`?

Comment: I manage to get that far more or less 
/hhhhhh\/{1}[a-z0-9]+\/{1}/g
but doesn't seem to stripe out the hhh part and both /

Comment: the structure of the url will always be the same

Comment: Please show us the code with which you have applied that regex to the string. What do you mean by "stripe out" for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need for regex, just split it

```
var link = "http://www.test.com/abc/hhhhhh/a458/example";
var linkParts = link.split("/");
//If the link is always in that format then a458 or whatever 
//would replace it will be in index 5
console.log(linkParts[5]);
```

Comment: will it work if there are more stuf after the example ?
like /example?abc=2&xyz=0&xxxx=2013-08-22&zzz=2013-08-24

Comment: also if it starts at abc can i then do linkparts[3] ?

Comment: @user2707774: Yes (unless you're getting `example` without the query string) and yes